# Can you clone a pipeline by using already existing JSON?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, dotnetnuke

I'm new to Data Factories but in reading over the basics it looks like the solution to my problem is very simple -- too good to be true.

The existing Pipeline successfully transforms data in a test environment to tables in SQL Azure.  There are 4 BLOB objects which have data which will end up in one table in SQL Azure.

The database is for a DNN site so it will be copied now to Dev, Test, possibly also UAT but ultimately to production.

It looks as simple as adding new pipelines to the existing Data Factory and just altering Database name the connection strings.  In production I'll set up a new user account so that's unique and no one can easily hack it.  That's simple enough.

The object names in the databases remain the same.  There are just 3 sites (Dev, Test, Production).

So it should just be that easy, right?  Create a new pipeline, copy and paste the JSON, alter the Database connection strings in the pipeline JSON and call it a day, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link that gives more detail about config files and why they don't exist in the Azure Portal.  Paul's Purple Frog Blog is referenced: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/01/using-azure-data-factory-configuration-files/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cloning the pipeline, JSON and altering the Database Connection Strings you should try ***to automate things*** which are gonna help you a lot.

Manual deployment always has a high error prone.

You can follow the below steps for

- You can import your ADF into Visual Studio, using the VS plugin
  [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureDataFactory.MicrosoftAzureDataFactoryToolsforVisualStudio2015)
- You can then use configuration files in Visual Studio to [configure
  properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-vs#use-configuration-files) for linked services/tables/pipelines differently for each
  environment like (Dev, Test, UAT/Production)

Comment: Obviously it also has to be deployed and exist where ADF can access it.  This is new stuff but I'm used to config files storing common variables and then accessing these with C#.net at run time.

The key vault would do a similar thing, will try both solutions.

I'll up vote each ... I think that's possible.

Comment: Just got around to creating the config file in VS 2015.

The article doesn't show how to access the properties.

Obviously that's JPath in any object in the project using the different connection strings.

OK, here's dev and test:
"name": "$.properties.dev.connectionString",  ...
"value": "Data Source=dev.database.windows.net;Initial ...

Comment: Just got around to creating the config file in VS 2015.

The article doesn't show how to access the properties.

Obviously that's JPath in any object in the project using the different connection strings.

OK, here's dev and test:
"name": "$.properties.dev.connectionString",  ...
"value": "Data Source=dev.database.windows.net;Initial ...
"name": "$.properties.test.connectionString",
"value": "Data Source=test.database.windows.net;Initial

OK ... with what syntax do I use to get by name the right value?  Where's that article?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to store the database credentials in an Azure Key Vault. You can reference it as a parameter.

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "azureSqlReportingDbPassword": {
            "reference": {
                "keyVault": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subId>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroupId> /providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault-name> "
                },
                "secretName": " < secret - name > "
           }
        }
   }
}
```

See also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment) for more details and the [Blog-Post.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/continuous-integration-and-deployment-using-data-factory/)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I might go with the VS solution and configuration files because I understand that better.  Both of these are a real help so I'll up vote each.